# Python bluetooth advertising

Tags: python, windows, sockets, bluetooth, pybluez

I am looking for a way to send data over Bluetooth using python from 1 computer to another (windows is what I use but if it works with other computers that's great). I have looked into sockets but I would like to be more similar to a broadcast and then narrow down if a condition is met. I have also tried different python libraries that have not ended up working. If this is possible and if anyone could help with this issue that would be great!

Comment: Do you want to use Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy? Which libraries have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tries pybluez and I would like to try both Bluetooth low energy and classic